# UIScrollView: getting a better presicion on contentOffset in scrollViewDidScroll:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am trying to implement something based on the `UIScrollView` delegates, `scrollViewDidScroll:` in particular. So I read the `scrollView.contentOffset` in the delegate method and it works great until I start scrolling faster, then the `contentOffset` just skips up to 50 points in Y coordinate:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get a **better precision** of `contentOffset`?

Comment: use for better precision scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation.

Comment: But `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` is called once the animation is concluded: 
**Tells the delegate when a scrolling animation in the scroll view concludes.

The scroll view calls this method at the end of its implementations of the setContentOffset:animated: and scrollRectToVisible:animated: methods, but only if animations are requested.**

Comment: Please inform me if you get a solution for the same. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Do you have any solution? I am facing the same issue. If you have answer, please inform me, thanks

Comment: My guess is that if the user scrolls fast enough, there will always be jumps. I don't think it makes sense for UIKit to update the value of contentOffset more often than once per animation frame (1/60 of a second). Perhaps you could log the timestamp at which the delegate method is called and see the **time** interval (not distance) at which each call happens.

Comment: Another possibility (long shot) would be to use KVO and observe changes to the value of `contentOffset`, independent of the delegate method calls. Not sure if this would work, though.

Comment: I think KVO on contentOffset will provide the same value/precision as the delegate call on scrollVidDidScroll...

Answer (score -1):

KVO will provide a message on every change, but the work you do in the observation 
method should be done quickly, so as to not induce lag...

To begin observing:

```
// assuming you have a scroll view outlet property
[self.scrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

To observe changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == self.scrollView) {
        NSLog(@"%f", self.scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    }
}
```

To stop observing:

```
[self.scrollView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset"];
```